# Multiply number by its own modular inverse and a constant

Tags: modular-arithmetic

We are given the following constant:

```
e = 17
```

We generate a random 64 bit prime p and then calculate q so that:

```
q = modinv(e,p)
```

This process is repeated until q is prime as well. Now I ran this and generate the following pair:

```
p = 17409780921729337789
q = 10241047601017257523
```

Now I calculate n = p*q:

```
n = 178294395142712253230038799435668436647
```

My question is, can I try to derive both p and q from n? Because essentially I have:

```
n = p * modinv(e,p)
```

which looks to be a simple equation with 1 unknown. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the solution: because of the way we construct q, we obtain the following equality:

$$(qe) - 1 = p j$$

where j is an integer. We can now express p as a quantity of q:

$$p = \frac{(qe)-1}j$$

Using the fact that n = q*p:

$$n =q(\frac{(qe)-1}j) $$

And we basically get a quadratic equation:

$$eq^2 -q -nj = 0 $$

Which we can now try to solve for various values of j.